# When running mvn versions:display-dependency-updates only some dependencies are processed

Tags: maven-3

When I run

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Only some of my dependencies are processed.

For instance I have this dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.kagkarlsson</groupId>
   <artifactId>db-scheduler-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Im not informed that there is a version 6.6 available. Why is that?

Im using maven 3.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your project pom.xml or your maven settings.xml is not overriding the central repository, if central repo is customized, it may not contain the recent version of this dependency

Comment: Thx. That was it =)